# Retornar uma soma em linhas distintas no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo uma tabela de extrato de depósito e retirada de alguns clientes, segue a tabela:

```
id_cliente|operação|valor |
----------+--------+------+
51298     |   01   | 50,00|
----------+--------+------+
51298     |   01   | 48,50|
----------+--------+------+
51298     |   02   | 13,67|
----------+--------+------+
51298     |   02   | 18,17|
----------+--------+------+
```

Operações com valores referente a 1 são depósitos, com valor 2 são saques.
Como faço para realizar uma consulta retornando o valor em saldo do cliente ? Um sql que já me retorne a diferença de valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua os nomes das colunas e da tabela:

```
select sum(case when operacao='01' then valor else 0 end) deposito,
       sum(case when operacao='02' then valor else 0 end) retirada,
       sum(case when operacao='01' then valor else -1*valor end) saldo
  from tabela
 where id_cliente = 51298
```

Answer (score 5):

### A função IF:

O MySQL já tem uma ferramenta própria para situações condicionais. É a função `IF`:

```
IF( expressão de teste, valor se verdadeiro, valor se falso )
```

### Aplicando ao caso da pergunta:

Basta um único `SUM` com `IF` para obter o saldo calculado em uma única passada pelo DB:

```
SELECT SUM( IF( operacao='01', valor, -valor ) ) AS saldo FROM tabela
```

Resultado:

```
saldo
66.66
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb5fe/1)**.

**Variantes:**

Se for para ver o saldo de um cliente específico:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(operacao='01',valor,-valor )) AS saldo FROM tabela WHERE id_cliente=51298
```

Se for para vários clientes na mesma pesquisa:

```
SELECT SUM( IF( operacao='01', valor, -valor ) ) AS saldo FROM tabela GROUP BY id_cliente
```

Answer (score 2):

você pode tentar desta forma

```
select sum(case when operacao=2 then valor*-1 else valor end) 
from tabela 
GROUP by id_cliente
```

Answer (score 1):

Pronto:

```
select 
   (sum(valor) from tabela where operacao = '01') - 
   (sum(valor) from tabela where operacao = '02') saldo
```

estou considerando que o campo operacao é um varchar/string. Se for numérico retire as aspas.

Comment: Não está faltando um "as" antes de "saldo"?

Comment: Essa tag é opcional