# É possível usar if else em consultas MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, if, else

Eu estive pesquisando na internet e ouvir rumores que e possível usar `if else` em consultas MySQL mas não vi nada de concreto a respeito. É possível mesmo? Se sim, como?

Eu quero fazer uma consulta em três tabelas distintas em busca da coluna nome eu tenho a seguinte *query* como exemplo

```
SELECT `PAIS`.nome, `FILHOS`.nome, `NETOS`.nome FROM `PAIS`, `FILHOS`, `NETOS` WHERE `PAIS`.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%' OR `FILHOS`.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%' OR `NETOS`.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%'
```

Essa *query* vai fazer uma consulta nas três tabelas `PAIS, FILHOS, NETOS` buscando por `'%MATILDE%'` no campo nome

Agora eu quero fazer como [nesse exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134823/45474) mas com SE

```
SE encontrar '%MATILDE%' na tabela NETOS CONCATENAR
CONCAT(' É FILHA DE ', FILHOS.nome),
CONCAT(' E NETA DE ', PAIS.nome)

SE encontrar '%MATILDE%' na tabela PAIS CONCATENAR
CONCAT(' É MAE DE ', FILHOS.nome),
CONCAT(' E AVO DE ', NETOS.nome)
```

Eu quero implementar algo mais ou menos assim.

Comment: Podes explicar que tipo que query precisas de correr?

Comment: Cite onde tem esse rumor.

Comment: se vc pesquisar ai gogre se acha @bigown > https://talibamartins.wordpress.com/2007/09/20/if-e-case-no-mysql/

Comment: ELSE eu nunca vi. O IF eu uso em algumas respostas no site. Uma delas é essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127134/70

Comment: Possível duplicata de [consulta recursiva em tabelas relacionadas usando foreign keys](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134823/consulta-recursiva-em-tabelas-relacionadas-usando-foreign-keys)

Comment: O que diferencia os "netos" na relação entre pais e filhos? Pois netos podem ser pais como podem ser filhos. Mesmo tento o mesmo sobrenome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No tipo de consulta que você pretende fazer, você pode resolver com uma subquery:

```
set @nome:='MATILDE';

SELECT CONCAT(' É MÃE DE ', f.nome) as filha,
       CONCAT(' É FILHA DE ', p.nome) as mae,
       CONCAT(' É AVÓ DE ',(SELECT nome from PAIS where nome like '%@nome%')) as neta,
       CONCAT(' É NETA DE ',p.nome) as avo,
    FROM `PAIS` p, 
         `FILHOS` f,
         `NETOS` n 
  WHERE `p`.nome LIKE '%@nome%'
     OR `f`.nome LIKE '%@nome%' 
     OR `n`.nome LIKE '%@nome%';
```

E usar a condição `IF` para ignorar a concatenação, já que nem sempre poderão haver filhas, netas, mães e avós no mesmo banco de dados, você pode fazer um filtro:

```
   SELECT  IF(f.nome IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(' É MÃE DE ', f.nome), null) as filha,
           IF(p.nome IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(' É FILHA DE ', p.nome), null) as mae,
           IF((SELECT nome from NETOS where nome like '%@nome%') IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(' É AVÓ DE ',(SELECT nome from NETOS where nome like '%@nome%'), null) as neta,
           IF(p.nome IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(' É NETA DE ',p.nome),null) as avo,
        FROM `PAIS` p, 
             `FILHOS` f,
             `NETOS` n 
      WHERE `p`.nome LIKE '%@nome%'
         OR `f`.nome LIKE '%@nome%' 
         OR `n`.nome LIKE '%@nome%';
```

**Obs:** sua pergunta ficou confusa, pois na relação que você apresenta, não ficou claro o que diferencia as "netas" na relação entre pais e filhas. Pois netas podem tanto serem mães como podem ser filhas. Mesmo tento o mesmo sobrenome, uma mãe poderá vir como sendo neta dela mesma se considerar somente a relação de nome.

Comment: voce chegou ao ponto  que eu estava qurendo se voce ver na minha outra pergunta voce vai ver essa busca eu fiz pelo campo nome mas eu criei uma tabela relacionando as na outra,  voce pode ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134823/45474 voce acha que tem como trazer essa relacao do banco de dados usando FK? @Ivan Ferrer

Comment: Acredito que sim... é bem tranquilo.

Answer (score 5):

Em SQL é possivel usar o CASE ELSE

```
CASE WHEN aaa = bbb THEN xxx ELSE zzzz END
```

Exemplo:

```
SELECT a, b, c, (CASE WHEN aaa = bbb THEN xxx ELSE zzzz END) AS d
FROM table
```

É compativel com SQL 92, funciona em SQL SERVER e [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Answer (score 3):

Isto é uma função quase igual ao que existe no Excel, ou como mais estamos acostumados na programação, funciona análogo a um [operador condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56812/101). O `ELSE` é consequência porque o primeiro argumento da função é a condição, o segundo é a expressão que ele deve retornar se a condição é verdadeira e o terceiro argumento é o que retornará se a condição for falsa, portando o que "seria executado" no `ELSE`.

[Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Então não é usado como controle de fluxo efetivamente, mas apenas como parte de um cálculo de valores (é como o operador condicional). Só dá para fazer coisas simples.

No comentário do Bacco tem [exemplo de uso real](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127134/101).

Até existe o [`IF/ELSE` pra controle de fluxo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html), mas não para usar em consultas SQL, aí é para programar funções e *procedures*.

Ali dá pra ver que pode usar um `CASE` também que funciona de forma semelhante, só que pode ter várias opções, ou seja, para cada valor achado na expressão principal (provavelmente uma coluna) haverá o retorno de um outro valor correspondente. è possível usar um `ELSE` nele também.

Então não chamaria de rumor, foi uma informação passada por alguém ser dar maiores fundamentos e referências. Sempre que possível consulte a documentação oficial. Ou pergunte aqui :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).