# Usar função IF em SQL como se fosse excel

Tags: sql, if, oracle11g, case

Existe no SQL uma função equivalente ao `IF` (`SE`) do excel? Preciso fazer um teste lógico que em excel eu escreveria assim `=SE(B1_UM = "UN"; D2_QUANT / B5_QE1;D2_QUANT)`.

Aqui está minha consulta:

```
SELECT
   D2_FILIAL,
   // Um monte de coluna...
   CASE
      B1_UM 
      WHEN
         'UN' 
      THEN
         D2_QUANT / B5_QE1 
      ELSE
         D2_QUANT 
   END AS CALC_QUANT 
FROM
   SD2010 SD2 
   // Vários joins
WHERE com várias condições
GROUP BY
   D2_FILIAL, 
   // Várias outras colunas no group
   CALC_QUANT
```

Comment: E qual a `query` que você está utilizando atualmente?

Comment: Qual é exatamente a condição que que você quer testar e o resultado que está esperando?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo estou querendo que a query faça um calculo baseado em um teste logico, conversei com um amigo e cheguei nesse resultado `CASE B1_UM WHEN 'UN' THEN D2_QUANT / B5_QE1 ELSE D2_QUANT END AS CALC_QUANT` aparentemente deveria funcionar porém o DB não está reconhecendo a alias que criamos está retornando o erro `Error : 904 - ORA-00904: "CALC_QUANT": invalid identifier`

Comment: Mhac você parece estar usando Oracle certo ?
Podes fazer da seguinte forma...

select 
case nome_coluna
when nome_coluna = 1 
   then 'Mostrar o que você deseja' 
when nome_coluna = 2
  then 'mostrar ....'
else then 'xxxxx'   end  as 'XYZ' 

No exemplo que você comentou faltou realizar a comparação entre o B1_UM = 'UN' ....

Comment: @LucasBrogni oracle11g

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível usar if else em consultas MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135034/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-usar-if-else-em-consultas-mysql)

Comment: [Veja essa resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/135041/78713) sobre esse assunto. Apesar de a pergunta ser sobre um banco diferente, a teoria explicada aqui é a mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Para tratar resultados condicionais no [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) você tem basicamente tres estruturas:

#### 1. IIF(*expressão boleana*, *valor se verdadeiro*, *valor se falso*)

Exemplo:

```
SELECT IIF(id = 1, 'VERDADEIRO', 'FALSO') as Expressao
FROM tabela
```

#### 2. CASE *expressão* WHEN *valor 1* THEN *resultado 1* (...) END

Exemplo:

```
SELECT CASE id 
           WHEN 1 THEN 'ID é 1'
           WHEN 2 THEN 'ID é 2'
           ELSE 'ID é outra coisa'
       END as Expressao
FROM tabela
```

#### 3. CASE WHEN *expressão boleana* THEN *resultado* (...) END

Exemplo:

```
SELECT CASE  
           WHEN id = 1 THEN 'ID é 1'
           WHEN id > 5 THEN 'ID é maior que cinco'
           ELSE 'Não sei o que fazer com o ID'
       END as Expressao
FROM tabela
```

Espero que isso tenha esclarecido suas dúvidas.

Comment: obrigado Diego, acredito que seja exatamente essa função que procuro. Porém estou com um problema,  estou com a seguinte função `CASE B1_UM WHEN 'UN' THEN D2_QUANT / B5_QE1 ELSE D2_QUANT END AS CALC_QUANT` aparentemente deveria funcionar porém o DB não está reconhecendo a alias e está retornando o erro `Error : 904 - ORA-00904: "CALC_QUANT": invalid identifier`

Comment: coloquei a query completa

Comment: @Mhac Acho que no seu caso o problema é que você colocou a coluna que é resultado do case, `CALC_QUANT`, no `group by`. Isso é outro problema diferente do que foi tratado nessa questão, você não pode agrupar por uma coluna que só existe no resultset de saída. Se agrupamento deveria ser em outro campo (`D2_QUANT `) ou usar uma função de agragação nessa coluna.

Comment: Diego eu estou realmente iniciando com o desenvolvimento em SQL, poderia me dizer como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: @Mhac Na verdade eu já disse. Mas cometi um erreo de digitação: _Seu agrupamento deveria ser em outro campo (`D2_QUANT`) ou usar uma função de agragação (como o `SUM`) nessa coluna_. Esse assunto não é tão trivial para ser discutido em comentários, se você ainda não conhece `sql`... Se eu encontrar aqui uma outra resposta que explique isso em maiores detalhes vou referenciar na pergunta.

Comment: Entendi, pensei que fosse mais simples de ser feito... Utilizei o excel como exemplo, pq em excel isso é uma função bastante simples. Obrigado pela ajuda, se conseguir a referencia agradeço.

Comment: @Mhac mas o `IF` é simples. E já foi feito, inclusive. Você está tendo problemas é no `GROUP BY`. É outra coisa.

Comment: @Mhac [Tira uns 10 minutinhos para dar uma lida nesse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228294/distinct-e-group-by-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ambas-as-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es). Está abordando bem esse assunto (GROUP BY).

Comment: Obrigado Diego, consegui resolver o problema. Como estava executando uma formula eu deveria ter colocado dentro de uma função, no caso `SUM` foi so colocar a função antes do teste logico que funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

O que você procura acredito que seja isso

```
select iif(sexo = 0, 'Feminino', 'masculino') from clientes
```

**Editado**

Corrigi o comando a cima

Como está citado [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), o comando IIF(condicao, respPositiva, respNegativa) deve funcionar se seu SQL SERVER for 2012+

Comment: Essa `query` não funciona no `SQL Server`. Sugiro aguardar mais informações na pergunta antes de responder...

Comment: quais informações vc precisa?

Comment: Pois é... Irei começar a aguardar mais informações, o @Mhac já modificou sua pergunta...

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro estou querendo que a query faça um calculo baseado em um teste logico, conversei com um amigo e cheguei nesse resultado `CASE B1_UM WHEN 'UN' THEN D2_QUANT / B5_QE1 ELSE D2_QUANT END AS CALC_QUANT` aparentemente deveria funcionar porém o DB não está reconhecendo a alias que criamos está retornando o erro `Error : 904 - ORA-00904: "CALC_QUANT": invalid identifier`

Comment: Mostre seu script inteiro se possível

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro coloquei completo