# Somar a mesma coluna por critério diferente?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, reportviewer

Estou tentando criar um relatório usando `ReportViewer` que faz um `SUM` na mesma coluna por criterio diferente. Minha query funciona bem no PHPMyAdmin mas no QueryBuilder do ReportViewer nao funciona e retorna um erro.

Como resolver esse problema ?

aqui minha query.

```
SELECT e.id, e.tipoOperacao, e.historico, 
SUM(CASE WHEN e.tipoOperacao = 'E' THEN e.qtdTransacao ELSE 0 END) AS QTDENTRADA,
SUM(CASE WHEN e.tipoOperacao = 'S' THEN e.qtdTransacao ELSE 0 END) AS QTDSAIDA,
e.dtTransacao, e.valorTransacao, e.usuario, e.produto_id, p.id AS Expr1, p.descricao, 
p.valorCusto, p.valorVenda, p.controlarEstoque, p.qtdEntEstoque, p.estoqueMin, 
p.estoqueMax, p.status, p.imagem, p.catproduto_id, p.unidproduto_id
FROM estoque e 
INNER JOIN  produto p ON (e.produto_id = p.id)
WHERE e.dtTransacao BETWEEN @DI AND @DF GROUP BY e.produto_id
```

Aqui o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127134/70

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a instrução `if`

```
SUM(IF(e.tipoOperacao = 'E', e.qtdTransacao, 0)) AS QTDENTRADA
```