# Dúvidas sobre o comando count sql

Tags: sql

Quando escrevo o comando `select count(carga > 40) from cursos;` qual a logica de contagem que o comando `count` está executando?

Esse comando funcionou no mysql contudo ele me retornou um resultado que não consegui identificar a origem. Não consegui entender o que o *count* identificou na base.

Comment: Basicamente ele contou quantas linhas carga > 40 deu nulo (o que na prática retornou quantas vezes o campo carga está nulo, pois nulo > 40 == nulo da mesma forma). Dei duas alternativas na minha resposta, se tiver dúvidas comente, que elaboro melhor. Mesmo você tendo comentado no texto, sugeriria por a tag MySQL além da SQL existente, pois varia muito o comportamento de banco pra banco.

Answer (score 4):

O `count(expressao)` não serve para o que você está tentando.

Ele retorna não conta "verdadeiro" ou "falso", e sim "quantas ocorrências de `expressão` não são nulas.

O `count(*)` é uma exceção, ele retorna todas as linhas, independente da nulidade.

Manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Duas soluções para o seu caso:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE carga > 40;
```

ou

```
SELECT SUM(IF(carga > 40, 1, 0 ));
```

Esta segunda, com `if`, pode ser entendida melhor nesse post:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127134/70

Answer (score 1):

O count() retorna o números de linha.
Por exemplo foram encontrados 5 registros com *carga > 40*, então ele retornara 5.

Para somar o valor dos 5 registros por exemplo use sum().

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria do seguinte modo

```
select count(*) from nometabela where carga > 40;
```

Neste exemplo ele irá contar os registos que foram selecionados
Os registos selecionados seria todos os que o valor de `carga` fosse maior que 40

```
 select count(carga) from nometabela where carga > 40;
```

se colocar `carga` em vez de `*` poderá ter problemas se carga for `null`